# 6 DOF Spherical Wrist IK Calculation (Unity)

Tags: inverse-kinematics

So i solved the first 3 Joints of this 6DOF but i dont know how to deal with the Rotation Matrix at Joint 4,5 and 6. I know that i need a XYX Rotation Matrix but I dont know how to affect the TCP with it.

This is my current State:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVI0FZqCo1g

If there are Questions about smth let me know

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Michael Musk, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inverse kinematics for 6 jointed robots](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/9622/inverse-kinematics-for-6-jointed-robots)